# Need an advice on where to initialize the local state in a component from a redux store value

Tags: reactjs, redux, initialization, react-redux

I am implementing a customer edit form page using react/redux. I will be fetching the customer details related to the customer ID in the componentDidMount method and will be storing the customer related data in the redux store. 
I want to use that data set as a model in the customer edit form page, and want to initialize the local state with the customer data which I have stored in the redux store. 
I want to know , in which component should I do that(setting the redux store model to the local state)? is it correct to do inside the constructor?

Comment: Initialize it wihitn the componentDidMount if you want it in local state but you can always fetch it from the store and update the same in store directly

Comment: is it correct to update the store directly ?

Comment: Why not, you sure can update the state but to that dispatch the actions and update through reducers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how your actions are designed and what the local state in this component actually is.

When the user changes an input's value in the form, do you want to store these changes in the redux store right away? Or do you want to wait until they confirm with a button, or maybe save changes automatically with a certain interval?

1. It's possible to update the redux store on *every* keypress the user does in the form - but you'll fire a lot of actions. In this scenario you won't need component state at all, the props hooked up to the redux store via `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are enough. All inputs would be controlled inputs.
2. If your component has some internal logic to run before propagating changes in the form to the redux store, you have to clone the form in either the `constructor` or `componentWillReceiveProps`. This depends on how your application is using the `CustomerEditForm` component.

   1. If you're using the `constructor`, you will not get updates from the redux store while the user is changing the form. Imagine another user edits the same customer, but your component won't know about it because it's not looking at `this.props.customerForm` anymore.
   2. If you're using `componentWillReceiveProps` you have to deal with keeping the form in sync with the redux store. Imagine there is an input `customerName` and you got its value from `this.props.customerForm.customerName` originally. Now this value might have changed in `this.state.customerForm.customerName` (because the user made changes to the input), but also in `nextProps.customerForm.customerName` (because someone else made changes). Now you have to decide what to display or discard.

I'd recommend to go with scenario 1. if possible, and only keep UI state in the component's local state (something like "dropdown menu is open").

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in constructor also but as you are using redux,setting your state in store and then retrieving data from it would be the solution i will recommend as it will be more flexible.

in case you set your state in component,it will do unnecessary renders even if you do not want that behaviour if your state changes.So store would be a better option